Knights, Knaves and Jokers with Layers
So, you escaped the first room. Spoiler for linked-to Q&A:

 You did it by rudely waltzing past pair $A$, who really wanted to participate in your torment. The overlords wish to correct this injustice, and so you entered this room...

In front of you is a knight (always telling the truth), a knave (always lying) and a joker (always answering yes or no randomly). We call these three gentlemen "triplet $A$", and you don't know who is who.
Behind them are $\displaystyle\binom{3+3-1}{3} = 10$ triplets, labelled $B_1$ to $B_{10}$. Each triplet is a set of knights, knaves and jokers, where the full set of triplets is the set of all combinations of knights, knaves and jokers, allowing for repetitions.
Behind the 10 triplets are two doors: door 1 and 2. One leads to freedom, and one to death, but you don't know which. Your goal is to guarantee your escape by asking yes-or-no questions to the knights, knaves and jokers, to which they will answer either yes or no. However, there are some rules:

You can only direct a question to a single knight/knave/joker at a time.
You cannot ask a member of triplet $A$ any questions regarding the doors.
Once you ask a question of a member of a triplet $B_i$, you cannot pose a question to a member of any other triplet.
Paradoxical questions, or questions about the future, will not be answered by anyone; joker, knight or knave.

Give a solution using the smallest maximum number of questions, and prove that it is indeed such a solution.
The next room...

Attribution: Me

"Behind the three pairs"?

@fljx Fixed now

This puzzle is much more complicated than the previous one.

 Nevertheless, my answer to it provides a hint to the present puzzle.


 Unfortunately, now there are jokers. Since we need to obtain information, it does not matter for us what jokers answer, it is just a bad luck to ask them. On the other hand, knights and knives are determined, so we can obtain information from them.


 Moreover, using the logical equivalence question form from my answer, we can always deduce the truth from an answer to such a question.


 This allows us to replace all knaves by knights. That is, for the sake of simplicity, from now we assume that all knaves are replaced by knights and the questions are asked in the direct from instead of the logical equivalence form.


 Then there is the following solution in five questions.


 Let $A$ consists of $A'$, $A''$, and $A'''$. We use the first question to detect a knight $K$ in the triplet $A$.


 Ask $A'$: "Is $A''$ a knight?"


 If the answer is "yes" then $A''$ is a knight, otherwise $A'''$ is a knight.


 We use the second question to detect a triplet $B_i$ with a knight.


 Ask $K$: "Is a knight in $B_1$?"


 If the answer is "yes" then put $i=1$, otherwise put $i=2$.


 We use the third and the fourth questions to detect a knight $K'$ in the triplet $B_i$.


 Since we already detected the knight $K$, we can ask him about $K'$.


 And we use the last question to ask $K'$ about the door to freedom.


 Although I failed to find a solution with less questions, I do not claim the optimality of my solution. I think that even if it is optimal then it is not an easy task to prove its optimality.


I don't quite understand the logic of your first question. If $A'$ is a joker, then the answer "yes" would mean that $A''$ is either a knight or a knave (though due to their equivalence it doesn't matter). If $A'$ is a knave, then "yes" would mean that $A''$ is not a knight (and would thus be a joker). If $A'$ is a knight, then they would say 'no', and you wouldn't know whether $A''$ is a knave or a joker. Am I missing something? Also, do not that your answer must contain some kind a proof that it is the optimal, unless it's obvious that it's optimal like in your last answer :)

Change the first question to ask A "Is either A' a knight or A'' a knave?" If A says "yes", then A'' is consistent; if A says "no", then A' is consistent.

@user110391 I updated the answer a bit by the respective explanations.

Aha, I understand now, took me a moment to get used to your abbreviated way of explanation, but it is quite elegant and nice. Also, due to the simplicity of your explanation, I think it's a small road from it to a proof of its optimality. If you don't find a proof I think I can make one tomorrow and drop you some hints or edit your answer to include it (if that's allowed), so that you may progress to the next room (or... I mean uh... freedom... hahah there's no next room I swear!).

Alex Ravsky gave a solution in

5 questions.

Let's prove that it's optimal.
First, fix a deterministic strategy using only

4 questions.

We'll analyze the scenario where we always happen to pose our questions to jokers if possible, and they always happen to answer yes. Our goal is to show that there are at most

4 different people

outside triplet A that could be questioned.
Next, split into cases based on

the number of questions posed to triplet A.


Case 0:

Questioning is restricted to one triplet, so at most 3 different people could be questioned.


Case 1:

The first question is posed to a joker who says yes, so questioning is again restricted to one triplet other than A, with at most 3 different people asked.


Case 2:

The second question could provide 2 different answers, but with only 2 different people that the third question could be posed to, it's possible that they're both jokers who say yes. In both cases, there's only 1 more person we could question, for a total of 4 different people questioned outside triplet A.


Case 3:

The second and third questions could provide 4 different pairs of answers, so there are at most 4 different people that the fourth question could be posed to. Note that a mixed strategy that poses the third question to triplet A or not depending on the answer to the second question also results in at most 4 different respondents outside triplet A.



Finally, with only

4 different people

outside triplet A that could be questioned, no matter how we distribute them between triplets, it's possible that all of them are jokers, giving no information about the doors. Therefore, guaranteeing escape is impossible using only

4 questions.


I didn't quite get the logic of your proof, so I posted my own. But I am quite sure my proof is correct and I assume yours is too, so I am now sure that Alex' solution is optimal, and I can accept his answer.

Let's prove that Alex Ravsky's answer of

 5 questions

is optimal. But first, what even is an optimal solution? I perhaps should have made this explicit in my question, but usually people assume this interpretation anyways: it is the solution that has the smallest maximum number of questions.

 Alex's solution has a maximum number of $5$ questions; is this the smallest maximum number of questions of all solutions?


 Firstly, let us ask to which triplet must our first question(s) be directed? Triplet $A$, or some triplet $B_i$? Due to the existence of the all-joker triplet among the $B_i$, we cannot guarantee freedom by choosing a $B_i$ blindly. The only triplet that we can guarantee contains a knight/knave at the start is triplet $A$. So, our first question(s) will be directed there.


 But, how many questions must we ask triplet $A$? Well, for any triplet containing a joker, for which we don't know who is who, we must always ask at least $1+x$ questions to answer $x$ questions about the world beyond that triplet. We must use at least one question to identify a knight/knave (who are just knights when one uses Alex's equivalence question form, and will thusly just be called knights from here on), and then we must use our $x$ questions to get our $x$ answers about the world beyond the triplet.


 So, in this scheme, we use $n \ge 1$ questions to find a knight in $A$, and then $x$ questions to find something out about the world beyond. But what information about the world do we want from $A$? Well, we cannot ask about the doors, so we must settle for finding a knight among the $B_i$. So, $x$ is the number of questions required to find such a knight. So, how do we proceed?


 Well, we could begin exhausting possibilities. "Is $B_1'$ a knight?", "Is $B_1''$ a knight?", et cetera. While this solution will have the smallest minimum number of questions, it will clearly not have the smallest maximum number of questions. We see that by merely observing how many nos we can receive. There are in total eight jokers among the $B_i$, so worst case, we must ask such a question eight times. We could try to divide our search up into looking for a suitable triplet first, and then looking for a knight within that triplet. One example of such a division would be first asking questions like "Does $B_i$ contain at most one joker?", so that once we locate a suitable triplet, we need only one more question before finding a knight. To these kinds of questions, how many nos could we receive before guaranteeing we've found such a triplet? Well, how many triplets contain more than one joker? Three triplets. So, after at most three questions, we've found a suitable triplet. Now, we must ask another question to locate a knight, meaning we would use at most four questions in our search for a knight among the $B_i$. Can we do better?


 Well, looking for a triplet with at most zero jokers would be even worse than the above. So, let's look for a triplet with at most two jokers, which is equivalent to looking for a triplet that isn't the all-joker triplet, or  equivalent to looking for a triplet that contains at least one knight. We need only one question to find such a $B_i$. Then, we ask our knight in $A$ about the gentlemen within $B_i$, where we will need at most two questions to find one, meaning we would use at most use three questions in our knight-search. This is better than all the other alternatives*, and is thus the best alternative.


 *This is a rather strong statement that must be proven. So, let's categorize our alternatives and prove this. Our first categories is "Asking questions searching for a knight among the $B_i$, and "Asking other kinds of questions". As we showed earlier, we must find a knight among the $B_i$, so the latter category will not contain the best alternative.


 Within the former category, we have the two possibilities: dividing our search up into firsly looking for suitable triplets, and then looking for the knight within a suitable triplet, versus not doing that. We showed that the latter was not the best possibility.


 Within the former category, we have three possibilities: looking for a triplet with at most two jokers, with at most one joker and with at most zero jokers. We showed that the first option was best among these three. Now, through our exhaustive categorization, we have shown it is the best among all options.


 So, we have that $x \le 3$, which means $x_{\text{max}} = 3$. Now, we must still ask the knight we find in $B_i$ about the door to "freedom", increasing the maximum number of questions asked $q_{\text{max}}$ by one. So, we have that $q_{\text{max}} = n + x_{\text{max}} + 1 = n + 4$, and that $n \ge 1$, meaning that $q_{\text{max}} \ge 5$. In other words, $5$ is our lower bound on the maximum number of questions needed.


 But Alex's solution uses at most $5$ questions, which means it is the optimal solution. End of proof.

